# Converting List of words to Problem Graph For Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm

Tags: networkx, directed-graph, namedtuple, digraphs, weighted-graph

I have been trying to construct a problem weighted Graph for Minimum Spanning Tree from a list or string of words as, given a string of words to list of named-tuple with every possible combinations of words as head and tail with additional head "root"

Input:

```
['john', 'saw', 'mary', 'root']
```

Required Output:

```
[Arc('root',weight,'saw'),Arc('root',weight,'john'),Arc('root', weight,'mary'),
 Arc('saw', weight,'john'), Arc('john', weight, 'saw'), Arc('saw', weight,'mary'),Arc('john', weight,'mary'),
 Arc('mary', weight,'john'),Arc('saw', weight,'mary'),Arc('mary', weight,'saw')]
```

Code:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple 

Arc = namedtuple('Arc', ('head', 'weight', 'tail'))

def Constrain_graph(sentence):
    Arc = namedtuple('Arc', ('head', 'weight', 'tail'))
    C_graph=[]
    for wordindex in range(1, len(sentence)):
        G = nx.DiGraph()
        G.nodes(sentence[wordindex])

        #G.add_node(nod)
        G.add_nodes_from(range(1,len(sentence)))
        C_graph=nx.Graph()
    return C_graph
```

I need the output to be like mentioned above

Comment: How do you call this function? The function does not return anything, so what do you consider the "output"? Why does your expected output have a duplicate, and not "john"-"saw"? Why do you have `continue` as the final line in the loop, as there is nothing to skip?

Comment: i am out of logic thats why the code is incomplete and i need to consider all the head tail combinations hence the duplicates .

Comment: I don't see where the minimum spanning tree comes in to play. It looks more like a complete graph, but even then... I don't understand what you are after. Even less I understand why this is tagged with `parsing`, or with `weighted-graph`.

Comment: the output would be the starting problem graph for the minimum spanning tree Algorithm.

Comment: So then your question has nothing to do with it. Are you looking for a complete graph?

Comment: No i need a directed weighted Graph as given Output because my spanning tree algorithm works only for such namedtuple data structure

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the logic of the required output you have provided.

Comment: Any relevant information should be in the question, so an SO member looking at your question can understand it and possibly post an answer.